# Angular 2 window global object is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

For reference:  https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/blob/master/Client/app/platform-modules/app.browser.module.ts#L51

Universal cache object is getting added globoally with initial state like this in the html that's sent to client:

```
<script>
  window.UNIVERSAL_CACHE = { } // stuff gets loaded here
</script>
```

In my `browser.module.ts` I'm trying to load that initial state:

```
// imports

export const UNIVERSAL_KEY = 'UNIVERSAL_CACHE';

@ngModule({
  // bootstrap, imports, providers, etc.
})
export class AppBrowserModule {

    constructor(public cache: CacheService) {
        this.doRehydrate();
    }

    // Universal Cache "hook"
    doRehydrate() {
        let defaultValue = {};
        let serverCache = this._getCacheValue(CacheService.KEY, defaultValue);
        this.cache.rehydrate(serverCache);
    }

    // Universal Cache "hook
    _getCacheValue(key: string, defaultValue: any): any {
        // Get cache that came from the server
        const win: any = window;
        /* I can console.log(win) to see the window object with .UNIVERSAL_CACHE, however if I console.log(win[UNIVERSAL_KEY]) it is undefined. */
        if (win[UNIVERSAL_KEY] && win[UNIVERSAL_KEY][key]) {
            let serverCache = defaultValue;
            try {
                serverCache = JSON.parse(win[UNIVERSAL_KEY][key]);
                if (typeof serverCache !== typeof defaultValue) {
                    console.log('Angular Universal: The type of data from the server is different from the default value type');
                    serverCache = defaultValue;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('Angular Universal: There was a problem parsing the server data during rehydrate');
                serverCache = defaultValue;
            }
            return serverCache;
        } else {
            console.log('Angular Universal: UNIVERSAL_CACHE is missing');
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `win[UNIVERSAL_KEY]` is always undefined even though I can `console.log(win)` and see it, or in the dev tools I can type `console.log(window.UNIVERSAL_CACHE)` and see it.  Any idea why that may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough reputation to just comment)

The problem come from this function which seems unfinished : https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/platform-node/node-platform.ts#L418

When I want to make the message disappear in production, I remove manually the `injectCacheInDocument` function from my generate js file.

Comment: Hey.  Thanks.  I think someone mentioned to use this in webpack.client.ts, which is help me:  `var ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
      async: ['client.bundle.js'],
      defaultAttribute: 'sync'
    })
  ]
};`